# Can't set headers after they are sent - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou criando um sistema de registro de usuários no NodeJS e preciso verificar se o email digitado já está cadastrado, está tudo funcionando normalmente, se eu digito um email já existente ele me retorna o id do usuário que utiliza este email. Porém, na hora que eu vou escrever um retorno na tela com o `res.send("");` a aplicação me retorna o erro do título.

(É uma API)

Meu código:

```
app.post('/account/new/validate', function(req, res){
    if(typeof req.body.emailRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.senhaRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.senhaConfirmarRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.nomeRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.cpfRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.nascimentoRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.cepRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.estadoRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.cidadeRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.bairroRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.ruaRegistro !== 'undefined' && typeof req.body.numeroRegistro !== 'undefined'){
        if(req.body.emailRegistro !== "" && req.body.senhaRegistro !== "" && req.body.senhaConfirmarRegistro !== "" && req.body.nomeRegistro !== "" && req.body.cpfRegistro !== "" && req.body.nascimentoRegistro !== "" && req.body.cepRegistro !== "" && req.body.estadoRegistro !== "" && req.body.cidadeRegistro !== "" && req.body.bairroRegistro !== "" && req.body.ruaRegistro !== "" && req.body.numeroRegistro !== ""){
            if(req.body.senhaRegistro === req.body.senhaConfirmarRegistro){
                var sql = app.config.dbcnx();
                var accountModel = app.app.models.accountModel;
                //Verificando se o email e o cpf estão em uso
                accountModel.verEmailExiste(sql, req.body.emailRegistro, function(error, result){
                    if(result.length > 0){ res.send("[EmailEmUso]"); }
                });
                accountModel.verCpfExiste(sql, req.body.cpfRegistro, function(error, result){
                    if(result.length > 0){ res.send("CpfEmUso"); }
                });
                res.send("ok");
            }else{ res.send("[SenhasDiferentes]"); }
        }else{ res.send("[CamposEmBranco]"); }
    }else{ res.send("[CamposIndefinidos]"); }   
});
```

Model:

```
module.exports = function(){
    this.verEmailExiste = function(sql, email, callback){
        sql.query("SELECT idUser FROM tblUsers WHERE emailUser='" + email + "';", callback);
    }
    this.verCpfExiste = function(sql, cpf, callback){
        sql.query("SELECT idUser FROM tblUsers WHERE cpfUser='" + cpf + "';", callback);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Já realizei diversos testes, a consulta sql está ok, não está retornando erro, está retornando um `result.length > 0` e quando chega no `res.send("");` da erro.

Eu já terminei um sistema de login nesse mesmo formato e funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está fazendo duas requisições assíncronas antes de enviar um `res.send("ok")` e dentro delas, você envia um outro `res.send(...)`. O que acontece é que depois que você der uma resposta para a requisição em `res.send()`, você não pode enviar uma nova resposta.

Você precisa implementar suas funções de forma que só seja enviada a resposta uma única vez. Uma das formas de você fazer isso é:

```
accountModel.verEmailExiste(sql, req.body.emailRegistro, function(error, result){
    // Lembre-se de dar um return ao final da sua condição
    // para que não continue a execução do código e envie
    // um outro res.send()
    if(result.length > 0){ res.send("[EmailEmUso]"); return; }

    accountModel.verCpfExiste(sql, req.body.cpfRegistro, function(error, result){
        if(result.length > 0){ res.send("CpfEmUso"); return; }
        // Tudo ok. Não tem ninguém com mesmo Email, nem CPF.
        // Agora você pode enviar uma resposta de ok
        res.send("ok");
    });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, eu pensava que quando eu enviava um response o código parava automaticamente, sem precisar de um return.

Comment: Eu também pensava isso, mas depois de verificar com um `console.log`, eu percebi a cagada hehe